# When importing a table from a PDF to Excel, spaces are being ommitted

Tags: excel, pdf, importdata

I'm trying to import a table from a PDF file to Excel (Excel 2021). To do so, I go to Data/get Data/from PDF and then I select the corresponding table.

The table contains 3 columns, the first two columns are numbers, and the third column is an address that always has the following format: 'abcstreet 23, 1243PB, abcland'.

When importing the table, everything is correct except for the fact that Excel omits the spaces between the addresses as follows:
'abcstreet23,1243PB,abcland'. This happens already from the preview of the table.

Do you know how to avoid Excel omitting the spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: I have tested sample data w/o any issue on Excel 365.